# c++ bitmask: explanation of a code block

Tags: c++, bitmask

I am new in c++ and i have some difficulties to understand bitmask. If someone could describe in the simplest way how the following code work (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C.2B.2B):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void comb(int N, int K)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // [0..N-1] integers
        {
            if (bitmask[i]) std::cout << " " << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));
}

int main()
{
    comb(5, 3);
}
```

I understand the purpose of this code and what is the output but i don't undertstand the initialization of the string bitmask `std::string bitmask(K, 1)`, and what the `resize(N, 0)` do.

Comment: Just read the documentation of such functions on a site like *cppreference*. This is a basic skill that you'll need; SO does not need a question about every basic use of every function.

Comment: @underscore_d the purpose of this site is not to help ? i read the doc of this functions but i don't understand all the things, this is why i asked for explanations. no need to be so agressive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string bitmask(K, 1)` creates a string called `bitmask`, and initialises it with `K` instances of the char `1` (note, **not** the char `'1'`).

The `bitmask.resize(N, 0)` then resizes the string to be of size `N`, and fills any gaps with the char `0` (again, note **not** the char `'1'`)

So if 'K' were `2` and `N` were `5`, you'd end up with a string containing the non-printable characters `1 1 0 0 0`

There are a few issues with the code as it appears to me - first of all, the constructor and `resize` should be passed `'0'` and `'1'`, not `0` and `1`. Secondly, it doesn't cater for when `N` is less than `K`

Comment: ok and then `prev_permutation` loop over all permutation: `1 1 0 0 0`,  `1 1 1 0 0`, .... and after we output `i` only when char is 1 ?

Comment: i presume it is a more efficient method than just use vector or array ? or the person did that just for the style ? :)